# Java process reports "incorrect" number of available processors

Tags: java, linux, runtime, numa, numactl

I'm running a Java 1.6 process on an 8-node NUMA machine using:

```
numactl --cpunodebind=0 java -server com.foo.Bar
```

Each node has 8 CPUs as reported by `numactl --hardware`:

```
available: 8 nodes (0-7)
node 0 cpus: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
node 0 size: ...
node 0 free: ...
node 1 cpus: 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
node 1 size: ...
node 1 free: ...
...
node 7 cpus: 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
node 7 size: ...
node 7 free: ...
```

The function call `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` returns `64`.

Why does the `Runtime` object for the process report 64 available processors, despite the `cpunodebind` restriction? Is there a way to get the actual number of processors available to the Java process?

Comment: Pass a command line property that indicates how you've restricted the configuration.

Comment: try passing `-XX:+UseNUMA` to jvm to make it aware of numa

Comment: @Hot Licks, that's a good workaround, but I was looking for something idiomatic.

Comment: (This is an interesting issue.  If Runtime doesn't know the number of processors then GC may not either, and that would cause it to create too many GC threads.)

Comment: Tried -XX:+UseNUMA on java 16, it doesn't help.